# How can I get the height of the wrapper after rendering the child?

Tags: reactjs, render, children, ref

I have a component Grid, and I need to get his height after render his children.
children are 100 images and their rendering speed is much lower than the Grid rendering speed.

```
import React, { FC, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

import { TProps } from '.'
import { Grid, Wrap } from './contentStyle'

export const ContentComponent: FC<TProps> = ({
    children,
}) => {

    const grid = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        isPageBottom && getNextVideosPreviewAction({ pageNumber, video })
        grid && grid.current && console.log('​height', height && height.current.clientHeight)


    })

    return (
        <Wrap>
            <Grid ref={grid}>
                {children}
            </Grid>
        </Wrap>
    )
}
```

In console log - 66, but in real - 3006

Comment: Define "much slower". Are the components loading data asynchronously or are they doing something else synchronously after the initial render? Maybe using `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect` will solve your issue.

Comment: @Chris, children loading after Grid render and stretch it
Grid - is a simle div

Comment: Does the below solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `useEffect` is run after the render, but before the N images are fully loaded. You'll need to wait for all the images to load before you can get the final height.

One option would be to use an `onLoad` callback on the images and keep track of how many images have been loaded. If all images are loaded, the element is now at it's full height, and we can access the final height.

```js
const App = () => {
  const data = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
  ];

  const parentEl = React.useRef(null);

  const [loaded, updateLoaded] = React.useState(0);

  const handleLoad = () => {
    updateLoaded(loaded + 1);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded === data.length) {
      console.log('Height:', parentEl.current.clientHeight);
    }
  })

  return (
    <div ref={parentEl} >
      {data.map(item => (
         <img style={{width: 140}} onLoad={handleLoad} src={`https://via.placeholder.com/600x600?text=${item}`} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell the alternative without React hooks? It would be very helpful.